# How to download a file that takes 5 seconds to finish with python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to write some code that would download a file. Now this file from this website specifically, once you go on to that link, it takes 5 seconds for it to actually prompt the download, for example: https://sourceforge.net/projects/esp32-s2-mini/files/latest/download

I have tried using the obvious methods, such as wget.download and urllib.request.urlretrieve

```py
urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://sourceforge.net/projects/esp32-s2-mini/files/latest/download', 'zzz')

get.download('https://sourceforge.net/projects/esp32-s2-mini/files/latest/download', 'zzzdasdas')
```

However, that does not work, it downloads something else, but not what I want it to.

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: This may be a job for `selenium`. It brings up a browser and interacts with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using chrome's download page (ctrl+j should open it, or just click "Show All" when downloading a file), we can see all of our recent downloads. The link you provided is just the page that begins the download, not the location of the actual file itself. Right-clicking the blue name lets us copy the address to the actual file being downloaded.[image: context menu of file from chrome downloads page]
The actual link of the file, in this case, is https://cfhcable.dl.sourceforge.net/project/esp32-s2-mini/ToolFlasher/NodeMCU-PyFlasher-3.0-x64.exe

We can then make a GET request to download the file. Testing this out with bash `wget` downloads the file properly.

```
wget https://versaweb.dl.sourceforge.net/project/esp32-s2-mini/ToolFlasher/NodeMCU-PyFlasher-3.0-x64.exe
```

You can, of course, use python requests to accomplish this as well.

```
import requests

response = requests.get(r"https://cfhcable.dl.sourceforge.net/project/esp32-s2-mini/ToolFlasher/NodeMCU-PyFlasher-3.0-x64.exe")

with open("NodeMCU-PyFlasher-3.0-x64.exe", "wb") as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

Note that we are using `wb` (write bytes) mode instead of the default `w` (write).

Comment: Right, and is there a way to scrape this download link properly? The thing is, I need to download 30 of these types of files at the same time with a Python script. I was able to upload url paths to a list and in that way add them as a string to the URL and do it like that. However, I am not exactly sure on how to acquire this link through scrapping

Comment: @MatasMikelionis I don't know off the top of my head. If you manually collect the links you might be able to get away with manually checking the download links from chrome. If you have a large volume of them/they're auto generated, you might have to do as tdelaney suggested in their comment and use selenium.